# Printing a diamond pattern in a diamond pattern using java

Tags: java, printing

I want to print out a pattern like this but I can't get it to work. The big problem I'm having is the lines outside the diamond and the parts in the diamond where there is just spaces. I have marked my output white different numbers to mark areas so i know what part who is doing what. 
I hope someone can help please.

Here is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        int rows1 = 10;
        System.out.println("## Printing the pattern ##");

        for (int i=1; i<=rows1; i++)
        {
            // Print space in decreasing order övre väster hörn tomrum
            for (int j=rows1; j>i; j--)
            {
                System.out.print(" 1 ");
            }


            // Print star in increasing order övre inre delen av triangeln tomrum
            for (int k=1; k<=(i * 2) -1; k++)
            {
                if( k == 1 || k == (i * 2) -1)
                    System.out.print("*");
                else
                    System.out.print(" 2 ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        for (int i=rows1-1; i>=1; i--)
        {
         // Print space in increasing order nedre västra härnet tomrum
            for (int j=rows1-1; j>=i; j--)
            {
                System.out.print(" 3 ");
            }
            // Print star in decreasing order nedre inre delen av triangeln
            for (int k=1; k<=(i * 2) -1; k++)
            {
                if( k == 1 || k == (i * 2) -1 )
                    System.out.print("*");
                else
                    System.out.print(" 4 ");
            }


            System.out.println();
        }

}
```

[How I want it to look or near it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zyedk.jpg)

Comment: Please dont put up images. The expected output pattern would be text, so please post it as text. And please add the **actual** output as well. Do not expect that people download your code, to then debug it for you.

Comment: The problem is that i cant give you the expected output pattern in text. then i wouldn't be here and asking for help.. So i gave what i have and if i should't use images why have they added that feature?                                                        And sure i can add my output but it looks like shit when i include it.

Comment: @Oscar Jansson You CAN give an expected output in text, you just need to type it yourself...from my point of view that image is no help I ran your code and I don't know exactly which ones you even want gone.

Comment: What diffrens do it do if i print it out in text or if you see it in a picture? and if you dont get my code so be it. The thing is i want it to look like the picture who you obviously have seen. But if you guys whant to i can delete this post and try again.

Comment: The point is that this community strives to be usable for everybody. There are people out there who need screen readers because they have problems with their eye sight. Text works for that group, images do not. Therefore images of something that could be presented as text are discouraged here.

Answer (score 0):

This class prints the image in the picture.
Basic idea is that you use the (left part of) the middle line of the diamond, to create the rest of the form.

```
public class Diamond {

    private String base;

    public Diamond(String base) {
        this.base = base;
    }

    private String reverse(String s) {
        return new StringBuilder(s).reverse().toString();
    }

    public void print() {

        int l = base.length();
        int c = (l/2)-1;

        String[] diamond = new String[l-1];
        diamond[c] = base + " " + reverse(base);

        String next = "/ " + base;
        for (int i = 1; i < l/2; i++) {

            String center = " ";
            if (next.endsWith("  ") == false) {
                center = "O";
            }

            next = next.substring(0, l);
            String bottom = next.replace('/', '\\');
            String bottomRight = reverse(next);
            String right = bottomRight.replace('/', '\\');

            diamond[c-i] = next + center + right;
            diamond[c+i] = bottom + center + bottomRight;

            next = "  " + next;
        }

        for (String line : diamond) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Diamond("  O O O O O     O O O       ").print();
    }
}
```